# Does the location of the double bond in chlorins yield a distinct biological function?

Tags: metabolism, photosynthesis

[Chlorins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorin) differ by the number of double bonds and their location. Chlorin has 20 pi electrons, whereas bacteriochlorin and isobacterichlorin have 18 pi electrons, but at different locations.

[image: Porphyrin, chlorin, bacteriochlorin]

Do chlorin, bacteriochlorin and isobacteriochlorin have distinct biological function due to this double-bond difference?

Answer (score 1):

I only found a hint that this might be the case in [this](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2989852/) publication by Singh et al., stating

> Porphyrins, chlorins, bacteriochlorins, and isobacteriochlorins each have unique photophysical properties that are **exploited by nature** and can be used for diverse applications (1, 2).

I don't have access to "[The Porphyrin Handbook](http://store.elsevier.com/The-Porphyrin-Handbook-Volume-1/isbn-9780123932013/)" (The first citation in the quote above), but I suspect it would be your best guess in finding more information.